# Why am I getting "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm new to Python so please have mercy on me.
My environment is:

```
  macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and Anaconda 4.3.16
```

I have to following code:

```
import os,
import urllib.request

IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TRAINING_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
```

I am running in Anaconda Spyder, and when I step through the code with F9, I get:

```
>>> import os
>>> import urllib.request
>>> IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
>>> IRIS_TRAINING_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"
>>> if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
... raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Why am I getting this error?

Charles

Comment: Huh? As you can see by my code above it is indented by four space.  I checked again and typed four spaces.  I still get the error!

Comment: This must be a bug in Spyder.  I just ran the script (outside of Spyder) with Python 3, and it worked without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) The *Run a line* feature in Spyder (what you get when you press <kbd>F9</kbd>) is meant to run full commands, i.e. lines that immediately produce a result. In your case, the line

```
if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
```

is not something that produces a result, and hence it generates an error in the next line.

So instead of using <kbd>F9</kbd>, I recommend you to use cells instead.

*Note*: Cells are chunks of code you can create by writing in your code comments of the form `#%%`. They are run with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> from the Editor.

Answer (score 2):

I've got

```
    '''
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

and couldn't find out what caused it. It appeared I accidentally made an indent in the very beginning of my code :)

I removed this indent and everything became fine!

[image]

Comment: I feel both immensely stupid and equally relieved after figuring out I was hitting the same issue.